# Map multiple JPA2.0 entity classes to the same table without inheritance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, openjpa

I have several entity classes which have more or less the same attributes but unfortunately I have no option to apply some kind of proper inheritance among each other. Nevertheless my goal is to map all of these entities to the same table in the database. Is there a way to achieve this goal by any conventional JPA2.0 means? I like the idea of using some kind of discriminator, but as far as i know this approach is only available in the context of entity inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your data in in a single table, perhaps using [Embeddables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables) will work for you?

Comment: Actually I dont get the idea of using embeddables in this context. Could you give me a little hint?